# Node.JS application CPU utilisation is getting high

Tags: node.js, redis, pm2

I've developed a application using Node.JS & Redis cache. In my application a CRON is running in every second. That CRON calling third party api, to get updated data. At a time CRON is hitting approx 40-50 third party API in a second & then saving into Redis cache.

A whole process is continuously happening in every one second.

In code doesn't have any errors. but CPU utilisation is 90-100 % most of the times.

Current configuration of server is 2 CPU, 4 GB RAM & 4 GB Swap file.

Is there any solution, why my cpu is high ? or is there any best alternative way to handle these type of scenario using node.js ?

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you calling `.disconnect()` to redis after your task is complete?

Comment: no. How can we do that ? With single redis operation or multiple redis operation ?

Comment: which one is best. Redis or Keydb?

Comment: depends on your use case definitely

Comment: I'm developing a betting website, on my betting website odds will be updated in realtime within milliseconds. So in this case what is a good option?

Comment: It is highly opinionated, but I would go with redis